# completion handler not returning anything even though its looks like it is when stepping through it

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, operation, completionhandler

Here is the function, its using Operation(NSOperation):

```
    typealias ResultType = Result<Data>
    typealias CompletionType = (ResultType) -> ()
    public var onCompletion: CompletionType?

  internal func getNetworkConnection(urlRequest: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionType)  {

        let task = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            if let errorResponse = error {
                //strongSelf.result = Result.failure(errorResponse)

                     strongSelf.onCompletion?(Result.failure(errorResponse))

            }

             if let responseFromServer = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200...299 ~= responseFromServer.statusCode{

                if let dataResponse = data{
                    //strongSelf.result = Result.success(dataResponse)


                    strongSelf.onCompletion?(Result.success(dataResponse))//it hits this point 


                } else {
                    strongSelf.onCompletion?(Result.failure(NSError()))
                }
             }

            strongSelf.urlSession.invalidateAndCancel()
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

I'm writing a unit test for it but it appears nothing is in completion block even though its hit the: `strongSelf.onCompletion?(Result.success(dataResponse))`

Here's what the unit test looks like so far:

```
func test_getNetworkConnection(){

    let promise = expectation(description: "Completion handler invoked")

  sut?.getNetworkConnection(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: requestURL), completionHandler: { (data) in

        print(data) //never prints

        promise.fulfill()
    })

    wait(for: [promise], timeout: 100, enforceOrder: true)//exaggerated timeout but it fails
  //  XCTAssertTrue(returnedResponse!)
}
```

Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: Are you testing the actual connection or are you testing a Mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. Inside the completion block of the data task, you are calling `strongSelf.onCompletion?...` but `onCompletion` is `nil` so it doesn't do anything.
2. Your `getNetworkConnection` function has a `completionHandler` parameter that you never use.
3. Your call to `getNetworkConnection` is depending on the `completionHandler` being called.

There seems to be no point to the `onCompletion` property.

Inside the data task, replace calls to `strongSelf.onCompletion?...` with calls to the `completionHandler` parameter.

```
typealias ResultType = Result<Data>
typealias CompletionType = (ResultType) -> ()

internal func getNetworkConnection(urlRequest: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionType)  {
    let task = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        if let errorResponse = error {
            completionHandler(Result.failure(errorResponse))
        }

        if let responseFromServer = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200...299 ~= responseFromServer.statusCode{

            if let dataResponse = data{
                completionHandler(Result.success(dataResponse))
            } else {
                completionHandler(Result.failure(NSError()))
            }
        } else {
            // TODO - need to call completionHandler here too
        }

        strongSelf.urlSession.invalidateAndCancel()
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: great that did it. Thanks a lot!